# Use multiprocessing for each recursion step

Tags: python, recursion, multiprocessing

My requirement is to generate a list permissible combinations. Below code is the simplified version which meets my need.

```py
def getChild(tupF):
    if len(tupF) <= 60:
        for val in range(1,10):     #in actual requirement, it is not a fixed range, but some complex processing to determing the list which need to be appended

            t=list(tupF)      #I am converting a tuple to list and after appending it, back to tuple as if I just handle as list, some how it didn't work
            t.append(val)
            getChild(tuple(t))
            t=[]
    else:
        print(tupF)


tup = ()
getChild(tup)
```

But, as the number of levels are high (60) and each of my combination is completely independent of each other, I would like to make this code multiprocess one.

I tried adding

```
            t.append(val)
            tmpLst.append(tuple(t)) 
            t=[]
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            pool = Pool(processes=3)
            pool.map(getChild,tmpLst)
```

But this didn't work as my worker process is trying to sub-divide further. In my case, I don't think the sub-process would explode as once the parent process has called a set of child process, I am OK with terminating the parent process as the all the desired information are in the tuple I am passing to the child process.

Please let me know whether this problem is right candidate for multiprocessing, if yes provide some guidance on how to make it multiprocess so that I can reduce the computational time. I have no prior experience in writing multiprocessing code, so if you can point to a relevant example, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: can I double check what you mean by "a list permissible combinations". Your code at the moment would produce astromonical number of prints

Comment: I have 17 variables, which are in specific sequence. I can calculate the list of permitted values for variable i based on values of variables 1 to i-1. With 17 variables, I get 1 million valid combinations.

Comment: I'm no wiser. What if I just have 3 variables a, b, c...Are you looking for combinations as in [a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc]? Are repeat like aaa allowed